# Read the COM1 output of a Hyper-V guest system

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, named-pipe

I have a guest O/S that writes debug output to the COM1 UART. This port is virtualized by the Hyper-V host. The Hyper-V Server allows only a redirection to a "named pipe".

I want to read what the guest O/S writes to this port. Since the Hyper-V server has not development tools like Visual Studio installed I would prefer to run the reader at a remote PC. The Hyper-V configuration dialog provides an option "Remote computer" what encourages me to ask in this direction.

Is there any description how can I make the output visible? I would prefer a kind of "terminal program" that allows to read, or a Powershell solution. But any hint is appreciated.